# pytrends return 'request' KeyError

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm trying to use pytrend to get several keywords from different countries over weekly periods
i don't know why but a much simpler code works, I'm not sure if it's the for loop or something else.

this is the code:

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360, )

contr = ['US', 'UK', 'IE', 'AU','CA','NZ',
        'PE', 'MX','VE', 'CO','AR', 'CL']
en_keyw = [['key1', 'key2', 'key3'],
        ['key4', 'key5', 'key6'],
        ['key7', 'key8', 'key9']]

weeks = pd.date_range('2018-12-1', 
                    '2020-06-20', 
                    freq='W'
                    ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

for i in range(len(contr)):
    for ii in range(9):
        for iii in range(len(weeks)):
            pytrends.build_payload(kw_list=en_keyw[ii],
                        cat=0, 
                        timeframe='{} {}'.format(weeks[iii], weeks[iii + 1]), 
                        geo=contr[i],
                        data = pytrends.interest_over_time(), 
                        gprop='')
            data1 = data.drop(labels=['isPartial'],axis='columns')
            dataset.append(data1)

result = pd.concat(dataset, axis=1)
result.to_csv('trends.csv')
```

but I'm getting a 'request' KeyError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
      27                         timeframe='{} {}'.format(weeks[iii], weeks[iii + 1]),
      28                         geo=contr[i],
----> 29                         data = pytrends.interest_over_time(),
      30                         gprop='')
     31             data = data.drop(labels=['isPartial'],axis='columns')

in interest_over_time(self)
    204         over_time_payload = {
    205             # convert to string as requests will mangle
--> 206             'req': json.dumps(self.interest_over_time_widget['request']),
    207             'token': self.interest_over_time_widget['token'],
    208             'tz': self.tz

KeyError: 'request'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that `pytrends.interest_over_time()` should be outside of `build_payload`, i.e.:

```
pytrends.build_payload(kw_list=en_keyw[ii],
                       cat=0,
                       timeframe='{} {}'.format(weeks[iii], weeks[iii + 1]),
                       geo=contr[i],
                       data=pytrends.interest_over_time(),
                       gprop='')
data1 = data.drop(labels=['isPartial'], axis='columns')
dataset.append(data1)
```

should be something like:

```
pytrends.build_payload(kw_list=en_keyw[ii],
                       cat=0,
                       timeframe='{} {}'.format(weeks[iii], weeks[iii + 1]),
                       geo=contr[i],
                       gprop='')

data = pytrends.interest_over_time()

if not data.empty:
    data1 = data.drop(labels=['isPartial'], axis='columns')
    dataset.append(data1)
```